# Looping through CSV to write error logs

Tags: regex, powershell, csv, logging, import

I am working with a text file (called `list_names.txt`) with comma separated values in it in the form of:

```
"old_name.pdf","new_name.pdf"
"old_name2.pdf", "new_name2.pdf"
...
```

The new_name column values are supposed to have letters followed by numbers (example: `abcd_12.pdf`), but some of them are recorded wrong and just contain numbers after an underscore (example: `_12.pdf`).

I would like to make an error log that records all the lines with this error and I tried to write a script for it.

```
$myHeader = echo OldName NewName

$csv = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\list_names.txt -Header $myHeader
foreach ($line in $csv) {
    if ($line.NewName -eq "`"`_[0-9]*.pdf`"") {
        Add-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\ocr_error.txt -Value "ERROR reading $line.FileName"
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get no output in the `ocr_error.txt`.

Comment: As the answer suggests, use the `-match` comparison operator.  Additionally, use single-quote string literals so you don't need to worry about escaping the double-quotes.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `-Match` and change your RegEx to `'^_\d*\.pdf$'`. You also need to use the subexpression operator `$()` to access the property of the `$line` variable in your Error output line:

```
$myHeader = echo OldName NewName
$csv= Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\list_names.txt -Header $myHeader 

Foreach ($line in $csv) {
    if ($line.NewName -match '^_\d*\.pdf$') {
        Add-Content -path $PSScriptRoot\ocr_error.txt -Value "ERROR reading $($line.OldName)" 
    }
}
```

The `-Match` comparison operator allows you to use a Regular Expression, where as `-Eq` does not.

You didn't need to include the speechmarks in your RegEx as they are removed automatically by the `Import-CSV`.

Per the comment from Ansgar, The RegEx pattern `'^_\d*\.pdf$'` ensures that it matches strings only where the `_` is at the beginning of the string followed by any number of digits (represented now by the regex token `\d` rather than a number range) and ending in `.pdf` (where a `\` needs to proceed the `.` to stop it being interpreted as a RegEx token).

Comment: Anchoring the regexp at the beginning of the string is required, otherwise file names like `abcd_12.pdf` would be matched as well. I'd recommend using `^_\d*\.pdf$` to avoid surprises.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, i've amended as such.

Comment: Additional note: he's trying to catch the double-quotes as well, so it should be `'^"_\d*\.pdf"$'`. If he's on PSv2, matching start/end doesn't work outside of `Select-String -Pattern` for some reason.

Comment: The double quotes get removed by import-csv I believe.

Comment: I just tested, and your assumption is correct @MarkWragg regarding the quotes.  The point about PSv2 still stands, however.  There are some specific use-cases where I've had to use start/end bounds together, and they do not work with the `-match` operator

Comment: `Foreach ($line in $csv | Where-Object {$_.NewName -match '^_\d*\.pdf$'}){`, using [**`Where-Object`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx).

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'm not aware of a situation where anchoring an expression at beginning and end would work in v3, but not in v2. Please provide evidence. The expression in question here works just fine in PowerShell v2.

Comment: You can go test it yourself @AnsgarWiechers go launch `-Version 2`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I tested it with an actual PowerShell v2 on an old XP testbox.